# How do i prevent mongoid from saving default values when doing an update_attributes( )?

Tags: mongoid

Is there a way to do this in mongoid?

I would just like my existing fields to stay nil and not take on the model's 'default' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently in Mongoid, I would suggest to open a feature request https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/new